# Python: Making inventory, not adding to the container

Tags: python, inventory

I'm trying to simulate an inventory, and the debugger isn't finding anything wrong, except
when I run the file to test it, it prints false to an item being added even though it should print true. It's not informing me that there is an error in the code, so I do not know where to look. If you could tell me what I need to change so it will return true at the end (`print(sword in bag)`) that would be a big help. Ty.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, quantity=1):
        self.name = name
        self.raw = name.strip().lower()
        self.quantity = quantity

        self.value = value
        self.netValue = quantity * value

    def recalc(self):
        self.netValue = self.quantity * self.value


class Container(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inside = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(list(self.inside.items()))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inside)

    def __containts__(self, item):
        return item.raw in self.inside

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.inside[item.raw]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.inside[item.raw] = value
        return self[item]

    def add(self, item, quantity=1):
        if quantity < 0:
            raise ValueError("Negative Quantity, use remove()")

        if item in self:
            self[item].quantity += quantity
            self[item].recalc()
        else:
            self[item] = item

    def remove(self, item, quantity=1):
        if item not in self:
            raise KeyError("Not in container")
        if quantity < 0:
            raise ValueError("Negative quantity, use add() instead")

        if self[item].quantity <= quantity:
            del self.inside[item.raw]
        else:
            self[item].quantity -= quantity
            self.item.recalc()

bag = Container("BagOfHolding")

sword = Item("Sword", 10) potion = Item("Potion", 5) gold = Item("Gold coin", 1, 50)

bag.add(sword)

print(sword in bag) print(potion in bag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you misspelled `__contains__` in your method definition.

Comment: oh wow, I skimmed that what felt like 100 times, genuine apology for wasting your time. Many thanks.

Comment: haha it happens to everyone @user3200666 all it takes is a pair of fresh eyes to notice :)

Comment: No worries, its pretty sneaky since the method defined is technically valid as is - it just doesn't work as you hope!